# __block ivar is always (null)

Tags: cocoa-touch

I've writen a class to parse XML on block. The completionHandler return an mutableArray and an error (if it happens), the problem is that I can NSLog the element of the array but if I init a __block NMutableArray with the array it return null:

```
__block NSMutableArray *imagesURLs;
   NCBlockParser *parser = [[NCBlockParser alloc] init];
   [parser parseXMLFromURL:url withElementsName:[NSArray arrayWithObject:@"element"] completionHandler:^(NSMutableArray *item, NSError *err) 
    {
    if (err) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[err localizedDescription]);
    }
    else {
        imagesURLs = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:item];
    }
    }];

   NSLog(@"%@",imagesURLs); // (null) here :(
```

Ideas?

Comment: Looks like you cut out a lot of code that would be useful here....gonna need more from you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, you have some confusion about how blocks work.

The `NSLog` line is run long before the block is ever executed. Your `imagesURL` variable is only filled out after your parse returns, which is being done asynchronously. Move that `NSLog` inside the block and you should see what you're expecting.

Comment: But I've to use that var outside the block. There is a way?

Comment: You need to evaluate how asynchronous programming works. I don't have enough information about your particular issue or architecture to help you much.